# Serverless: Unexpected multiple "--type" (aliased by "-t") values

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I am getting an `Error: Unexpected multiple "--type" (aliased by "-t") values` in serverless. I run the code line `serverless invoke -f function -t Event -s dev -path .\events\task_data.json`, where task-data.json contains the following:

```
{
    "type": "task",
    "name": "daily_kpis",
    "data" : {
      "daily_kpis" : {
        "force": "true",
        "backfill" : {
          "from_dt" : "2023-07-24",
          "to_dt" : "2023-07-25"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The program this invokes lies on AWS.

I have tried to use `--type` instead of `-t`. I have tried to take the `"type": "task"` out of the task_data.json, in case this somehow conflicts.

The exact same program (pulled from GitHUB) with the exact same task_data.json and exact same serverless call works for a colleague of mine. Which makes me think that it may be a problem with my setup.

Is there a possibility to list where serverless finds the additional `type` or default location where serverless is looking for e.g. default `type`-parameters that could cause the problem?